# Handler cannot cancel asynctask in higher api

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

In my app I am using an asynctask for an operation.But I am also using a handler to cancel my task in case of time-out.

this is my handler operation

```
Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    };

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.arg1 = 0;
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
```

and this is my asynctask start

```
    final findIpTask task = new findIpTask(1, 2);
    task.execute();
```

and in my asynctask I have

```
protected void onCancelled() {

        running = false;
        dialog.dismiss();
                     //some alert dialog for time-out
```

in 2.33 emulator it is working fine.but when I run my app on a 4.0 emulator it doesn't stop.does anybody know why and have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTask doesn't stopped due to not stopping or cancel of Handler Thread.

Instead of using handler use **timer thread**, you can stop your thread and asyncTask, as shown in snippet below.

```
 Timer myTimer = new Timer();
  myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
//Your Stuffs
 }
  }, 0, 1000); // put your delay here 

           
if(ButtonStopped == true){
     myTimer .cancel();
     myTimer .purge();
     //your stuffs
     task.cancle();// call here for stopping your asyncTask
     }else{
         //your stuffs
                  
            }
```

For more info [go to this Android Developer link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: and to set time-out duration how?

Comment: buttonstopped? where did it come from sorry ? also, am I gonna put my task.execute into run(){}? then when will I call mytimer.cancel ?and what will I put as "my stuff" after timer.purge

Comment: @FatihKaplan -- when you click on stop button or when and wr you want to stop call timer.cancle followed by purge(). What you want to stop n all. its just an example. Go according to your structure.

Comment: I want a time out, like after 10 seconds I want it to be cancelled.